# how to use opencv or numpy to differentiate between image and a live person

Tags: python, computer-vision, biometrics

I have a face recognition model for detecting and recognizing faces, the problem I have with this is, it identifies a printed photo as well (that is it can be spoofed), I want to implement a check or algorithm that verifies if the person in front of the camera is real or if it's a printed photo.

My model returns landmarks of the facial features `[left_eye, right eye, nose_tip, left_lip, right_lip]` I was thinking that I can calculate  `the ratio of the distance from the nose_tip to the left eye and the distance from the nose_tip to the right eye`. I was hoping that this for a 2d image will change very less over a few frames let's say 10`diff< 0.2` but for a live human, this change/diff will be greater.

I don't want to make changes to the existing model so that's why I am trying to use such a technique. Is there a way to determine liveliness/differentiate a 2d image and a live person without making changes to the existing model? Kindly suggest if you have any inputs on this.

Comment: research "biometrics"

Comment: Just look for movement such as blinking. Or any change in the image that cannot be explained by a perspective transformation of a flat surface.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz kindly share if you have any resources.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I thought of blinking but it's not viable approach in my case.

Comment: try the *second* sentence then. get face landmarks.